# Find an integer $x$ such that $107 \equiv x \cdot 2005 \, \pmod{1302}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If I write it out then

$107 \equiv x \cdot 2005 \pmod {1302}$

means that

$x\cdot2005 = q1302 + 107$, for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ (I could replace 2005 with 703 though that doesn't make it any easier as far as I see)

How do I proceed without checking every possible $x$? I mean, I could write it as $(107 - x\cdot2005)/1302$ and wonder for which $x$ this has an integer solution, but that doesn't bring me any further.

If I plug it into Wolframalpha then I get $x = n\cdot 1302 + 941$, how do I get to this solution?

Comment: Do you know how to use the Euclidean algorithm to find the multi plicative inverse of 2005 modulo 1302?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wrote:

$$107 \equiv 2005x\pmod{1302} \implies 2005x - 1302n = 107$$

Now we have a linear Diophantine equation, which is easy to solve using extended Euclidean algorithm.

First we check whether the conditions are fulfilled. The GCD of 2005 and 1302 is 1. 1 is also multiple of 107, which means that this Diophantine solution has integer solutions.

There are infinite amount of solution to this equation. I come up with one rather big solution, but after simplifying it the smallest positive integers solutions are $(x,n) = (941,1449)$

We know that we add 1302 to $x$ and 2005 to $n$, we'll obtain another solution. But we are not interested in n, so the general formula for $x$ is:

$$x = 1302n + 941\quad\forall x \in \mathbb N_0$$

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea it was called a diophantine equation. Truth be told, I did contemplate using the extended Euclidean algorithm, but I wasn't sure how I'd get to 107. Didn't make the connection that if gcd is 1 or a divisor of 107, you can just multiply... ugh!

Comment: Hope you know how to solve the equation. If you don't I can publish my solution and explain it. ;)

Comment: Yep, I do know how to apply the algorithm, just didn't connect the dots :-). I got the same answer as you did.